# Java: I can run in command prompt if I don't include a package, if I do include a package I get no class found errors

Tags: java, eclipse, path, command, noclassdeffounderror

I can run a println `hello world` program fine in eclipse console view, with or without including a package.

If I try to run from the command line, I can only run the class file that was created without a package.

I change the command line dir to the location of the class file in both circumstances. If I created the class inside a package, I get a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:`

I have researched this a lot, and lots of people talk about a class path. If you are going to talk about this, please be very specific. All I know about this is

1)you have to set the path when installing java in your environmental variable

2) There is a classpath file that is located in the same folder as the bin and src folder of my package.(no idea what this is)

3) if you right click on the package or class while in eclipse and select build path, the properties for Java build path come up. There are source, projects, libraries, and order & export tabs here. I have no idea what any of these do.

Again, If you are going to advise with anything referring to any kind of path or class path, please be very specific for a NEWBIE. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Java requires full path(including packages) of the class to run a program. So if your class is in a package structure such as :

```
abc.xyz.MyClass
```

then while running it you need to give this path:

```
java abc.xyz.MyClass
```

But if your class is in default package then you can simply run it using

```
java MyClass
```

Eclipse is an IDE to make your life easier, so when you run your class in eclipse, behind the scene it uses the proper package+classname to launch your file. IDE are there to make your life easier, and hence eclipse is doing so.